# pass input a value stored in redux and make it editable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an input that I pre-populate with a value from elsewhere in redux stored in `state.model.operationLength` that is passed to the input as `this.props.operationLength.value` the user then sees the input below with a value already in the input, however the value is then not editable, if I try to change it, it triggers the action in redux but doesn't change the value,

if there is no value in `state.model.operationLength` then the input is editable and will store the value typed in

How can I make it so that the value is editable if a value is already stored?

**component.js**

```
<TextBox
  type="number"
  defaultValue={ this.props.height / 100 * 66 }
  placeholder={this.props.height / 100 * 66}
  onChange={newValue => this.props.setOperationLength(newValue)}
  tooltip="invalid"
  value={this.props.operationLength.value || ''}
  isValid={this.props.setOperationLengthValid}
  state={this.props.operationLength.isValid}
/>
```

**textbox.js**

```
class TextBox extends React.Component {
  onChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    value >= this.props.placeholder && value <= 3000
      ? this.props.isValid(true)
      : this.props.isValid(false);
    this.props.onChange(value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Box invalid={!this.props.isValid}>
        <Label
          rollo={this.props.designation === "rollo"}
          pleating={this.props.designation === "pleating"}
        >
          {this.props.label}
        </Label>
        <span>
          <Input
            type={this.props.type && this.props.type}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            value={this.props.value || ""}
          />
          mm
          <Tooltip>
            {this.props.state === false &&
              this.props.value !== null &&
              this.props.value <= 3000 &&
              "number entereded is too low"}
            {this.props.state === false &&
              this.props.value !== null &&
              this.props.value >= this.props.placeholder &&
              "number entereded is too high"}
            enter a number between ({this.props.placeholder} and 3000)
          </Tooltip>
        </span>
      </Box>
    );
  }
}

export default TextBox;
```

**actions.js**

```
export function setOperationLength(operationLength) {
  return {
    type: SET_OPERATION_LENGTH,
    operationLength
  }
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import {
  SET_OPERATION_LENGTH, SET_OPERATION_LENGTH_VALID, SET_OPERATION_PRISTINE
} from '../../constants/actionTypes.js';

const operationLengthReducer = (state = {
  isValid: false,
  pristine: true,
  value: 0
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_OPERATION_LENGTH:
      return {
        ...state,
        value: action.operationLength
      };
    case SET_OPERATION_LENGTH_VALID:
      return {
        ...state,
        isValid: action.isValid
      };
    case SET_OPERATION_PRISTINE:
      return {
        ...state,
        pristine: action.pristine
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default operationLengthReducer
```

Comment: What do you have in your reducer to handle SET_OPERATION_LENGTH action type ? When you say the action is fired but the value is not updated, do you mean that the state updates but not the component, or the state does not update at all ?

Comment: it works fine if `state.model.operationLength` is null when the user goes to type in the input, it will update with the value from the input, but I also have `state.model.operationLength` updated in another input so the input will be pre-populated  with a value when the user goes to type into the input and then it won't update

Comment: What won't update ? The input value only, or the redux state as well ? Also, can you show your reducer for SET_OPERATION_LENGTH ?

Comment: the input value and the redux state both don't update,  I've added the reducer

Comment: This is strange, your reducer clearly states to update the value.. Are you sure the redux state is not updated ? Have you tried to put a breakpoint (or a console.log) in the SET_OPERATION_LENGTH case statement to make sure the reducer is called ?

Comment: And if you did, does the action.operationLength match with the new value ?

Comment: I can see on redux devtools that when i type into the input it is firing off the SET_OPERATION_LENGTH action, and also the value stays the same without updating